# Python Code to Automate Abaqus Run Script

Tags: python, python-3.x, abaqus

[Error with Subprocess addition](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bvdS1.png)
[This is the error I get regarding the abaqus module](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kvZQg.png)

I'm quite new to python and so please don't mind if this question might seem silly.

So I have python file that does the function of opening an abaqus viewer and I have another python file that describes the functions I want to do in the abaqus viewer.

I need a piece of code that can automate the second script without me having to manually go into file>run script.

Script to Open Abaqus:

```
import os
import subprocess

os.startfile('Q:/win_apps/scripts/simulia/Abaqus/6.14-3/Use_these_if_not_working/abq6143_viewer.bat')
```

And then I have a python script that has the code regarding my output requests from abaqus viewer.

What line can I add to the above file to automatically take the second python script and run it?

Answer (score 1):

When running Abaqus with the typical start up scripts you can pass Abaqus/Viewer a script to run from the command line:

`abq6143 viewer noGUI=script.py`

where you replace script.py with the name of your Python script. This will start up Abaqus/Viewer with no user interface, run the script, and then quit.

If you want the user interface to come up and automatically run your script you can use the `script=` command instead of `noGUI`:

`abq6143 viewer script=script.py`

I see that you're using a custom batch file to start up Abaqus/Viewer. Without seeing those contents I couldn't say exactly how you would integrate the above, but you will probably need to adjust the relevant line in the batch file with the `noGUI` or `script` command.

Comment: I'm not trying to run the python script from the command line of the abaqus software, but instead from the CMD of my pc. Basically I am trying to write a code that opens the abaqus viewer software and then automatically runs a script and gives me the result. The code I've shown up there opens the abaqus viewer, I need help with how to ask the software to now run the python script. When I use the above method you've mentioned, it says abaqus module not found. I hope you understood my issue. Or let me know I'll try to explain in a different way. Thanks in advance!

Comment: Yes, I understand. Those commands in my answer are for the command prompt on your PC. If you were able to run those commands and Abaqus started up it should be able to import the abaqus module. Perhaps you could update your question with a screenshot of the error. That might help me understand your situation better.

Comment: I've added an image of the error I am getting when I tried your solution. Click on the link in my question. Thanks in advance!

Comment: Thanks @JoseThomas. You put the command into a Python script, but that's not correct. Those are commands that need to be entered directly into the command prompt. If you need to open Abaqus from a separate Python script then have a look at the Python `subprocess` module for starting processes from Python.

Comment: I've added the subprocess to my python script and still am facing an error. I've attached the error in the new link added above. The script is being run seperately rather than in abaqus viewer. Hence it says no abaqus module. Is there a way to rectify that.

Comment: @JoseThomas you don't need to import the abaqus module in that script. I would recommend trying to run that `abq6143` command directly in the command prompt as a first step. That way you can make sure the command works, before trying to sort out how to execute in within a Python script.

Comment: When I do that,in the command prompt, the error I am getting is - "abq6143 is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file."

Comment: @JoseThomas you'll need to work with whoever setup your Abaqus environment on how Abaqus is started. That's why I mentioned in my answer that it might be an atypical setup for you because of your custom batch file (`Q:/win_apps/scripts/simulia/Abaqus/6.14-3/Use_these_if_not_working/abq6143_viewer.bat`). However, this is all unrelated to your original question. If you can locate the command that opens Abaqus then you just need to add the `noGUI` or `script` argument to open it up and run a Python script automatically.